# Regular expression needs to NOT match if href or src is preceeded by a dot

Tags: php, regex

The title pretty much explains it, I keep matching ga.src when I don't want to be, otherwise this is a great solution. Could someone tell me what is wrong?

Not working

```
~(?!.)\b(?:href|src)\s*=\s*(["\']?+)\K(?:/(?!/)|(?=[\s>]|\1))~i
```

Works but matches .src .href

```
~\b(?:href|src)\s*=\s*(["\']?+)\K(?:/(?!/)|(?=[\s>]|\1))~i
```

Comment: The lookbehind syntax is `(?<!)` and you need to escape the dot `(?<!\.)`

Comment: @HamZa worked perfectly, please post as an answer so I can upvote and accept =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(?!.)` is a negative lookahead which checks if there is no character ahead (except for newline), which doesn't make sense. You want a lookbehind and the dot should be escaped `(?<!\.)`.

Read about lookarounds on [**www.regular-expressions.info**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)